# Leaping Lizards!

Tags: code-golf, number

Suppose we define a simple program that takes an array L of natural numbers with some length N and does the following:

```
i=0                 #start at the first element in the source array
P=[]                #make an empty array
while L[i]!=0:      #and while the value at the current position is not 0
    P.append(L[i])  #add the value at the current position to the end of the output array
    i=(i+L[i])%N    #move that many spaces forward in the source array, wrapping if needed
return P            #return the output array
```

Every such program will either run forever or will eventually terminate, producing a list of positive integers. Your job is to, given a list P of positive integers, produce a shortest list, L, of natural numbers that terminates and produces P when plugged into the previous program.

Such a list always exists, since one can just add `P[i]-1` zeros after each `P[i]` in the list, then one final 0, and it will produce the original list. For example, given `[5,5]`, one solution is `[5,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0]`. However, `[5,0,5]` is much shorter, so the automatic solution is not a valid one for your program.

```
[5,6]->[5,6,0,0]  
[5,7]->[5,0,0,0,0,7,0,0]
[5,6,7]->[5,6,0,7]
[5,6,8]->[5,0,8,0,0,6,0,0,0]
[1,2,3,4]->[1,2,0,3,0,0,4,0]
[1,2,1,2]->[1,2,0,1,2,0,0]
[1,3,5,7]->[1,3,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,7]
[1,3,5,4]->[1,3,4,0,5,0,0]
```

Input is a list of positive integers(in some format you can specify) and output should be in the same format. List and integer size can be up to 2^16. This is code golf, so shortest program in bytes wins!

Comment: Are you sure that handling arbitrary lists of up to 65536 elements in 10 minutes is feasible? Do you have a reference implementation which achieves it?

Comment: Just an FYI, the sandbox is more effective when used for longer than 3 hours :P I understand it can be  tempting to post right away, but I think Peter's comment shows how this question could have benefited from a longer run there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python 3, <s>109 102 100 95</s> 93 bytes

```python
def f(L,k=1,i=0):
 P=[0]*k
 for x in L:x=P[i]=P[i]or x;i=(i+x)%k
 return P[i]and f(L,k+1)or P
```

A recursive solution.
Call it like `f([1,2,3,4])`.
[Watch it pass all test cases.](http://ideone.com/KjRTnr)

We start with `k=1` (length of output) and `i=0` (position in output), and make a list `P` with `k` zeros.
Then we iterate along the elements `x` of `L`, updating `P[i]` to `P[i]or x` (so `P[i]` keeps its value if it's nonzero) and `i` to `(i+P[i])%k`.
After that, we check that the final value of `P[i]` is zero, incrementing `k` if it's not, and return `P`.

If at any point of the algorithm `P[i]` is already nonzero, it enters a loop going around some of the nonzero values of `P`, and ends up at a nonzero value; then we recurse.